# How do I get the file name in a webpack parser?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm working on a plugin that collects exports with a particular name from the modules. I've gotten the data out of the individual files via the parser export hooks, but I can't seem to find out how to pull out the actual module that the parser is operating on.

```
// hook into the module factory and get the exports
compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap(pluginName, factory => {
    factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap(pluginName, parser => {
                    parser.hooks.export.tap(pluginName, (node) => {
                        this.parseMetadataNode(node);
                    });
    });
});
```

parseMetadataNode is the method that does the actual extraction of the export, which is working well.

How do I find the module or userRequest that the node is operating on?  I need the file name of that node!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, in webpack docs, [this exportImport hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/parser/#exportimport) seems to be a combination of `import` and `export`, it seems to give you both the node and the source -- have you tried using this hook instead?

Comment: Getting the node data works well.  I can parse that like a charm.  It's getting the file name that's the issue, because the nodes don't seem to be associated with a file name, to my best ability to understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably check `parser.state`

```js
compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap(pluginName, factory => {
    factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap(pluginName, parser => {
         parser.hooks.export.tap(pluginName, (node) => {
           const { module: { rawRequest } } = parser.state;
           // ..
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think `parser.state.module.resource` is better. It has the absolute file path to your source file without any prefixing of loader paths. Also, [`parser.state.current === parser.state.current`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.46.0/lib/NormalModule.js#L485-L486).